# Asp.net Bundling relative path issue for different sub path

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I am getting error files inside the css codes.

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/global/plugins/globalStyle").Include(
         "~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
         "~/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css",
         "~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "~/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css",
         "~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css"
        ));
```

After `~/assets/global/plugins/` path there are two paths for my files. I got errors for fontawesome etc.

this is is font-awesome.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and it is output path `assets/global/plugins/Style/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0`, original file is in  `assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0`

These are plugin files so I do not want to change these codes, due to update issue.

I get same problem other bundlings too, like images etc.
How can I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've looked at bundling, so I apologize in advance if I'm sending you down the wrong path.

I think the easiest way to get this working would be to use the CssRewriteUrlTransform.  For example:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/global/plugins/globalStyle")
   .Include("~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```